# Solr Quickstart tutorial: "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI"

Tags: java, apache, solr, centos

I am following the [solr quickstart tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html), and I was unable to even make it halfway down the page before running into issues.

I downloaded the tarball [here](http://supergsego.com/apache/lucene/solr/6.0.0/) using wget, and then ran a tar -xvf on it.

I attempted the VERY first command...

```
bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt
```

And get hit with the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
```

To be honest, this is quite frustrating. Java is not my forte, so I am unsure what to do here. I was hoping this would be pretty plug and play, but I suppose not.

I googled the error message, and found similar, but not the same, error messages. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is not with Solr, solr is pretty much plug and play .

You have misaligned the instructions with download, Solr changed the way the binaries are organized and command line instructions . You have download binary with version 6.0 . while the instruction set you are using for 5.3 and that's exactly whats frustrating you .

Either download the solr 5.3.1  version [Solr 5.3.1 Download](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/5.3.1/) or use instructions for 6.0 [Solr 6.0 Instructions](http://yonik.com/solr-tutorial/) and you should be good to go.

Comment: I ran bin/solr start, and now it is saying something about not finding a start.jar file... 

"ERROR: start.jar file not found in /root/downloads/solr-6.0.0/solr/server!
Please check your -d parameter to set the correct Solr server directory."

Comment: confirmed I grabbed 6.0

Comment: trying to find this start.jar... elasticsearch was not this difficult to set up

Comment: I also had to cmod 755 the solr script bc it was saying I didn't have permissions.

Comment: k, finally got it. Needed to grab the .tgz and not the .srz.tgz

Comment: I ran into the same problem with the current version 8.3 and it helped me! For anyone else looking here, download the .tgz file, do not download src.tgz.